# Recover RAID5 volume after temporary failure of controller

Tags: linux, lvm, raid-5

I have an LVM RAID5 configuration, where two LVs are currently not active because one SATA controller did not properly resume from suspend, consequently leading to two devices, i.e. two PVs, failing. Unfortunately, it seems Linux managed to write to two LVs spanning those disks (the whole VG contains a number of volumes more, which also span the two PVs, all of which activate fine) before crashing fatally. After rebooting hard, the hardware reports no errors and thus my assumption that the suspend cycle crashed the firmware of the SATA-controller somehow. The error message is pretty much what's reported in the most similar question:

```
# vgchange -a y
```

results in the following messages in journal:

```
Dec 04 13:53:56 hostname kernel: md/raid:mdX: not enough operational devices (2/3 failed)
Dec 04 13:53:56 hostname kernel: md/raid:mdX: failed to run raid set.
Dec 04 13:53:56 hostname kernel: md: pers->run() failed ...
Dec 04 13:53:56 hostname kernel: device-mapper: table: 254:21: raid: Failed to run raid array (-EIO)
Dec 04 13:53:56 hostname kernel: device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
Dec 04 13:53:56 hostname kernel: md/raid:mdX: device dm-16 operational as raid disk 0
Dec 04 13:53:56 hostname kernel: md/raid:mdX: not enough operational devices (2/3 failed)
Dec 04 13:53:56 hostname kernel: md/raid:mdX: failed to run raid set.
Dec 04 13:53:56 hostname kernel: md: pers->run() failed ...
Dec 04 13:53:56 hostname kernel: device-mapper: table: 254:21: raid: Failed to run raid array (-EIO)
Dec 04 13:53:56 hostname kernel: device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
```

For the sake of the working volumes, I did not want pull one of the disks at random and follow the suggestion [here](https://superuser.com/a/1718697/514966), although that's the closest I could find, to get the system fully going again. I would have to migrate all the PVs from other LVs to another disk to pull that off it seems.

I was able to restore the RAID into working conditions by issuing:

```
# lvchange --resync VG/missinglv1
# lvchange --resync VG/missinglv2
and
# vgchange -a y
again
```

So this no longer the Q&A format, because I found the solution while researching the question. But since I had to find this from the documentation, I thought I'd post the result here.

Answer (score 1):

The command `lvchange` with option `--resync` allowed to proceed. I'll report here, if later on data corruption surfaces.

Comment: Complete answers at the time of submission is best

Comment: Been looking for this for weeks, or off and on maybe for years.